# How to autowire Spring @ConfigurationProperties nested objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When using Spring Boot `@ConfigurationProperties` binding, is it possible to autowire *nested* objects (i.e. make them a prototype bean). This would allow auto-config to instantiate a Domain Model instead of just some data beans that require further post-processing.

If post-processing *is* required, what is the best way to get **Spring** to post-process an object (as opposed to user doing it manually in each case).

Adapting [Spring's documented example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties):

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("my.service")
public class MyProperties {

    private List<Security> security;

    // getters / setters...

    @Scope("prototype") // FIXME elevate this class into a bean ...
    public static class Security {
    
        @Autowired // ... such that basic stuff like this works
        private MyService service;
        
        private String username;
        private String password;
    }
```

(Spring Boot 2.5.3)